# Multiples of length division algorithm c++ question

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, modulus

**Problem Statement**

You are given an array *a* of *n* integers.

You want to make all elements of *a* equal to zero by doing the following operation exactly three times:

Select a segment, for each number in this segment we can add a multiple of *len* to it, where *len* is the length of this segment (added integers can be different).

It can be proven that it is always possible to make all elements of a equal to zero.

Input
The first line contains one integer *n* (1 ≤ *n* ≤ 100000): the number of elements of the array.

The second line contains *n* elements of an array *a* separated by spaces: *a1*,*a2*,…,*an* (−10^9 ≤ *ai* ≤ 10^9).

Output
The output should contain six lines representing three operations.

For each operation, print two lines:

The first line contains two integers *l*, *r* (1 ≤ *l* ≤ *r* ≤ *n*): the bounds of the selected segment.
The second line contains *r*−*l*+1 integers *bl*,*bl*+1,…,*br* (−10^18 ≤ *bi* ≤ 10^18): the numbers to add to *al*,*al*+1,…,*ar*, respectively; bi should be divisible by *r*−*l*+1.

**Example**

**input**

4

1 3 2 4

**output**

1 1

-1

3 4

4 2

2 4

-3 -6 -6

**Code Solution**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
 
int64_t minv(int64_t a, int64_t m) {
    assert(0 < a && a < m);
    if (a == 1) return 1;
    return m - minv(m % a, a) * m / a;
}
 
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false), cin.tie(nullptr);
 
    int N; cin >> N;
    vector<int64_t> A(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> A[i];
    }
 
    if (N == 1) {
        cout << 1 << ' ' << 1 << '\n' << -A[0] << '\n';
        cout << 1 << ' ' << 1 << '\n' << 0 << '\n';
        cout << 1 << ' ' << 1 << '\n' << 0 << '\n';
        exit(0);
    }
 
    int64_t invNm1 = minv(N-1, N);
    assert(invNm1 * (N-1) % N == 1);
 
    vector<int64_t> op1(N);
    vector<int64_t> op2(N-1);
    for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
        op2[i] = -A[i] % N * invNm1 % N;
        assert((A[i] + (op2[i] * (N-1))) % N == 0);
        op1[i] = -(A[i] + (op2[i] * (N-1))) / N;
        assert(A[i] + (op1[i] * N) + (op2[i] * (N-1)) == 0);
    }
 
    cout << 1 << ' ' << N << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << op1[i] * N << " \n"[i+1==N];
    }
    cout << 1 << ' ' << N-1 << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
        cout << op2[i] * (N-1) << " \n"[i+1==N-1];
    }
 
    cout << N << ' ' << N << '\n';
    cout << -A[N-1] << '\n';
 
    return 0;
}
```

**Question**

I believe the code is using an extended euclidean algorithm for minv, and I really need help to visualize what's going on with the minv part. Also, I'm having trouble following the logic inside the for loop with the op2 and op1 equations and how the code produces the output from the input provided. Would anyone please share explanations to the code with the equations and logic here?

Answer (score 0):

`minv` function finds modular multiplicative inverse. Meaning, for a given number `a`, its inverse modulo `N` is a number `b` which satisfies `a*b % N = 1`.

[Extended Euclidian algorithm can be used to find such inverse.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

As for:

```cpp
cout << op1[i] * N << " \n"[i+1==N];
```

This is just index trickery with bools. `"<space>\n"` has a type <strike>`char[2]`</strike> `char[3]`, thus indices can be used to select between a space and a newline. Bool can be used to index such array since bools are implicitly convertible to `int`s - `true->1`, `false->0`.

Comment: Minor nit: `"<space>\n"` has the type `const char[3]`; the third character is the terminating `'\0'`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You are right, of course. Thank you.

Comment: sorry, I meant op2[i] = -A[i] % N * invNm1 % N and op1[i] = -(A[i] + (op2[i] * (N-1)) / N would you help with details for those?

Comment: Last question, how the code does the operation exactly three times?

Comment: @randomvalue Look at those asserts, the operations are constructed in such way that the asserted equation holds. Another hint is to look which segments the author selected.

Comment: I see all that, it's a puzzle to me and I don't have the missing pieces. Would you please help piece together the puzzle? Because the choice of op1 using N and op2 using N-1 with op2 working with modulus but op1 does division operation after negation I really don't know why or how they're both supposed to equal 0

Comment: @randomvalue Just substitute `op1,op2` into  `A[i] + (op1[i] * N) + (op2[i] * (N-1)) == 0` and see that the left side is indeed 0. The catch is that op1 divides by N and is then multiplied by `N`. They do not cancel each other, since it is integer division which rounds down. And the rounded amount is exactly the `op2` term = that is the first assert, because the mod N part is what was lost during the integer divison in `op1`.  The reason for dividing at all is because both `op1` and `op2` must be in multiples of the segment length - `N,N-1`.